# Python ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Read timed out

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am writing the following line of code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
tickers=['RELIANCE.NS','MBECL.NS']
mystocks=pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    mystocks[t]=wb.DataReader(t,data_source='yahoo',start='2015-1-1')['Adj Close']

mystocks
```

But this is returning the
`ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Read timed out.`

Accessing yahoo finance from browser works. I was able to do this until last week, but now the same line of code is throwing a Connection Error.

Comment: This code runs for me as-is, so there is likely something interfering with the network connection.  It is entirely possible it is on yahoo's end.  I would proceed with generating an equivalent curl command and seeing if something like changing the user agent or URI path changes the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you put the code for getting the dataframe in a try / except statement. This way it will wait until your connection is reestablished.

```
for t in tickers:
    try:
        mystocks[t]=wb.DataReader(t,data_source='yahoo',start='2015-1-1')['Adj Close']
    except:
        continue

mystocks
```